# squid remove leading slash from target url

Tags: proxy, squid

I am configuring squid as proxy to forward request and intend to allow request only to `example.com`. This is the request as made from my browser: `http://111.222.333.444/http://example.com` where 111.222.333.444 is IP of my proxy server, where squid is installed.

But I am getting **Invalid URL** error, while the server is trying to fetch `/http://example.com` (note leading slash), here is access log record:

```
1505858815.396      0 12.34.56.78 NONE/400 3687 GET /http://example.com - NONE/- text/html
```

Here is the configuration that I am using

```
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1
acl localnet src all            # Allow access from everywhere

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
acl safe_url url_regex example\.com.*

http_access allow safe_url
http_access deny all
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager

http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
http_port 80
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Got it! squid is proxy hence need to do the proxy connection to the server. If using firefox it can be done by setting up proxy and entering proxy server IP and port number. Once done URLs can be used directly in this case, use this directly in the navigation bar: `http://example.com`

More on how to setup proxy on [Firefox](http://www.aston.ac.uk/library/staff/mozillaproxy/) and [Chrome](https://customers.trustedproxies.com/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=10)